# Oracle Implicit Partition Pruning

Tags: database, oracle, query-optimization

I am trying to optimize a long-running stored procedure at my company. From checking the query plan, it looks like we could make some nice gains by writing the query to allow for better partition pruning. The trouble is, it seems like doing so would create a very verbose query. Essentially, we have a bunch of tables that have a foreign key to client and "sub-client". In many cases, data is not shared between clients/sub-clients so we partitioned on those IDs for each table. Here's a sample query to show what I mean:

```
SELECT ...
FROM CLIENT_PRODUCT cp
INNER JOIN ORDER o ON o.product_id = cp.id
INNER JOIN PRICE_HISTORY ph on ph.product_id = cp.id
WHERE cp.id = ?
```

All of the tables have a foreign key that references a client and sub client. The same client product cannot belong to two different clients or sub clients (Sorry. This example is using made up tables and is a bit contrived)

I can improve partition pruning by doing the following:

```
SELECT ...
FROM CLIENT_PRODUCT cp
INNER JOIN ORDER o ON o.product_id = cp.id and o.client_id = l_client_id and o.sub_client_id = l_sub_client_id
INNER JOIN PRICE_HISTORY ph on ph.product_id = cp.id and ph.client_id = l_client_id and ph.sub_client_id = l_sub_client_id
WHERE cp.id = ? and cp.client_id = l_client_id and cp.sub_client_id = l_sub_client_id
```

With this change, I just explicitly say what partition Oracle can look at for each join. This feels pretty gross though because I've added a bunch of mostly repeated SQL that doesn't functionally change what is returned. This same pattern would need to be applied for many joins (larger than the example)

I know that our application has an invariant that any Order for a Product must belong to the same Client and Sub-Client. Likewise, any Price-History item must belong to the same Client and Sub-Client as the Product. The same idea applies to many pairs of tables. In an ideal world, Oracle would be able to infer the Client and Sub-Client for each join from the other tables in the join because of that invariant. It does not seem to be doing that (and I understand that my specific invariant does not apply to everyone). Is there a way I can get Oracle to do this implicit partition pruning without me needing to add all those additional conditions? It seems like that would add a lot of value across the codebase and remove the need for all these "unnecessary" explicit joins.

There's also the possibility that I'm just totally overthinking / misunderstanding this so other suggestions would be great.

Comment: Please show us the table definition include indexes

Comment: You may know that your *"application has an invariant that any Order for a Product must belong to the same Client and Sub-Client"* but does the database? Do your data structures and constraints express that business rule to the database? For instance, are you using [referential partitioning](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-54D18B18-6838-4115-9389-E1FB0D20A8CA.htm)? Beyond that, I'm not sure I understand your objection to including the partition keys in the join conditions. Generally speaking, our queries benefit from being as expressive and explicit as possible.

Comment: @APC I guess I was mostly asking how to express that business rule to Oracle through data structures/constraints. Looks like referential partitioning is the right fit for my use-case. I want an "implict" partitioning because there are many instances in the code base that already join but do not include partition keys. Since the keys are not necessary for the correctness of the query result, it seems like developers should not need to worry about it. Also, I'd want to avoid the refactor if possible. Thanks!

Comment: We can't use Online Redefinition to implement Referential Partitioning. So you'll have to rebuild all the affected tables in downtime. Depending on where you are in the project lifecycle refactoring the PL/SQL might be by far the easier option.